# PuTTY Log to relative path?

Tags: windows-10, putty

I have a portable installation of PuTTY that I run from multiple PCs.  I'd like to log my sessions to a subfolder where the executable is located.  I've tried a few different options, but I get the following errors:

```
Error writing session log (raw mode) to file: logs/2016-09-30 132039.log
Error writing session log (raw mode) to file: /logs/2016-09-30 132053.log
Error writing session log (raw mode) to file: ./logs/2016-09-30 132102.log
```

Is this possible? Am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backslashes `\`:

```
logs\2016-09-30 132039.log
.\logs\2016-09-30 132102.log
```

Windows file paths use backslashes to delimit folders.  Windows also prohibits forward slashes `/` in filenames which prevented the file from being created.

Note: The middle option starting with a backslash won't work, because a filename cannot start with a backslash.